# Revoked Directory permissions for application, but the Graph API still reads data

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have defined an app in my Azure Active Directory over a year ago, and back then, I played around with the required permissions until everything seemed to work.

From back then until a few minutes ago, that app had two permissions on "Windows Azure Active Directory": "Read Directory Data" and "Sign in and read user profile".

[image]

But then I revoked them and clicked "Save":

[image]

I gave the AAD a few minutes for synchronization, before logging into Graph API again with that app's ClientID and Key and the corresponding TenantID, but I found that I could still read directory data.

---

Originally, I was debugging the opposite issue in another app. The other app is configured the same as this one, with the same permissions ("Read Directory Data" and "Sign in and read user profile"), but it always threw the error

> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}

If any of the login information is wrong, the error returned is different (400 Bad Request or 401 Not Authorized), so login works, but it seems that the app doesn't have the required permissions to access the directory data.

[While browsing the web I found that the app needs more permissions to be able to read directory data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441216/insufficient-privileges-error-when-trying-to-access-azure-graph-apis)

I cannot preclude that my first app once had these other permissions set and "revoked" again, so I have to think the unthinkable:

**Could it be that permissions to an app, once granted, are never really revoked again?**

---

UPDATE: No, it's not as easy as that. Not only are they not revoked, for new apps, they are not set either. Even if I check all permissions on the new app, the "Insufficient privileges" error is still there:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Permissions stay as long as the JWT authentication token is valid. The permissions are encoded in the JWT token by the token issuer (login.microsoftonline.com).
The lifetime is (AFAIR) one hour.

If you log in again and get a new token, it should not get the old permissions. You can decode the JWT tokens on sites like [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) or [jwt.calebb.net](http://jwt.calebb.net).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure as you change the permissions for your application that you are forcing the logged in user to re-consent, so that the new permissions get written for the user.

I believe the logic in the directory is such that if you already have permissions consented to, then the token service will grant tokens based on those already consented permissions. If new permissions have changed since the last time the user consented, those permissions will not apply because the user never consented to them.

What you can do is force re-consent by adding to your login url the query string "prompt=consent" where you should then be able to see all the new permissions required by the app, and hopefully this will fix your insufficient privileged issue.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: There is no user logged in to the application. My Windows Service is connecting to Graph API using the application's ClientID and TenantID and Key, and should be able to read data from Graph API without further authentication.

Comment: Even applications that do not have a user present MUST first request consent before they can function. This means that you will have to have a user sign in to the application to update the permissions still.